# Python Flask executing old function even after updating it

Tags: python, caching, flask, browser-cache, flask-cache

I am new to using Flask. I have written basic Flask code for Hello World but after updating function I am still seeing old value on the web page. From what I read on other posts and blogs, this might be Cache problem. But I am not sure how to clear it.

Old Function:

```
def hello_world():
    print('Hello World')
```

New Function:

```
def hello_world():
    print('Hello Hi')
```

I am still seeing `Hello World` as an output in the web page instead of `Hello Hi`.

I am running code in PyCharm 2018.2.5 if this helps

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_caching import Cache

app = Flask(__name__)
cache = Cache'(config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    print('Hello Hi')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cache.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        cache.clear()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include what you expect to see vs. what you actually see.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Does your project have any .pyc files? Delete them, as the program might be running from them.

Comment: Does it work if you stop using your cache?

Comment: @TonisF.Piip: Where can I find them? Inside project I have .pyc files but those are in lib folder

Comment: @noslenkwah: How do I stop using cache?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted machine. One more process was running API that is why even after making changes they were not reflected. I am still not sure which process. But it is working fine now.